# Remove empty icon spaces on androidx preferences

Tags: android, android-xml, android-preferences, androidx

I have just migrated my project to use `androidx` libraries. The new preferences/Settings Screen now displays empty icon spaces as shown in the picture [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/organize-your-settings#split_your_hierarchy_into_multiple_screens).

I tried the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/) with no luck. How to remove the empty icon spaces before preferences?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the empty icon space with this:

```
app:iconSpaceReserved="false"
```